# How safe is MutableContextWrapper

Tags: android, webview, memory-leaks, mutable-context-wrapper

How safe is the Android's `MutableContextWrapper` to use in terms of memory leak etc? I am instantiating a `WebView` with an `Activity`'s context and later want to change its context to another `Activity`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27326823/3292108) is an answer that warns of using `MutableContextWrapper` for `WebView` as it can cause leaks with mix of contexts. But i dont see any reason as how can it cause leaks when we change its context? 
Why shouldnt we change a View's context once its been intialized?

Has anybody used in and faced any problems(specially for `WebView`)? Are there any precautionary measures while using it?Any data to  share for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not safe. There are actions on `Context` that require counter-actions in order to free up resources, e.g. `Context.registerComponentCallabacks`, `Context.registerReceiver`, and if you change the Context in the meantime, that means the counter-actions will not be called for the initial context, resulting in resource leaks. And WebView uses these actions, that's for sure.

Note that WebView is a much more complex component that a regular View, because it contains a network stack, a rendering engine, etc.

Comment: but AdMob is also using MutableContextWrapper. I checked it after decompiling  the Google Play services code in a class which extends WebView. I can see there that they are instantiating that webview using MutableContextWrapper.

Comment: As I understand, they sometimes need to use the Application context instead of the Activity context, that's why they use MutableContextWrapper. It's not for passing WebView between activities.

Comment: If they just need to use AppContext, they can save it in another variable and use it when required. But they are actually changing the context of WebView ( but in both cases they are using AppContext)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, by "they need to use" I actually meant that they need to pass a different context to WebView in certain situations. But it seems to be done only to work around some bugs.